# How do I get the `layout_weight` of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, layoutparams

I have a `TableLayout` and a row with a couple `TextViews`. I want to find the `layout_weight` of the `TextView` but I cant figure out how. I've tried the following:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = tv1.getLayoutParams();
```

and:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = tv1.getLayoutParams();
```

In the first case I get a type mismatch: "Cannot convert from ViewGroup.LayoutParams to TableRow.LayoutParams", and the second case works fine, however `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` doesn't have a `weight` field.

All the different types of `LayoutParams` are confusing, I'm never sure which to use where.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689896/setting-the-layout-weight-of-the-textview-under-the-tablerow

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView text = new TextView(v.getContext());
text.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) link

Comment: Setting the `LayoutParams` isn't a problem. It works with both `TableRow` and `TableLayout` `LayoutParams`. The problem is I can't get the `layout_weight` because `getLayoutParams()` returns a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` object which doesn't include weight.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it with your first try. You just need to cast to the correct type:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = (TableRow.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
```

Any subclass of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` (including `TableRow.LayoutParams`) will have a `weight` field.