# getLayoutParams() has not weight attribute (Android)

Tags: android

i tried to get the `android:layout_weight` in my function. this is my xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    ......
    </LinearLayout>
```

And the Part of my function:

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;

....
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myID);
```

But when i try to call `layout.getLayoutParams()` there is no `weight` variable, only width, heigth, ...
Is this beacause of the imported packages or why does `getLayoutParams()` not have weight?

this is the same issue as here, but he also couldn't solve it: [How do I get the `layout_weight` of a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334391/how-do-i-get-the-layout-weight-of-a-textview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual type of the layout parameters that are used in a view depend on the type of container it sits in. Not all layout parameter types have a `weight` field. If your layout is part of another `LinearLayout` (or one of its derived classes, such as `TableLayout` or `TableRow`), then you simply need to cast the value returned from `layout.getLayoutParams()` to the correct type. For instance:

```
float weight = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams()).weight;
```

You don't say exactly what kind of layout class your `layout` view lives in, so I can't be any more specific than this.

Comment: works for me! Thank you very much! @TedHopp Please, do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/wO9G2N